# Fade Screen to specific color using glsl

Tags: glsl, fragment-shader

I want to fade the screen to a specific color using glsl 
So far this is my glsl code and it works quite well:

```
uniform sampler2D textureSampler;
uniform vec2 texcoordOffset;
uniform vec3 sp;
uniform vec3 goal;
varying vec4 vertColor;
varying vec4 vertTexcoord;
void main(void) {
  vec3 col=texture2D(textureSampler, vertTexcoord.st).rgb;
  gl_FragColor = vec4(col+((goal-col)/sp), 1.0);
  //gl_FragColor = vec4(col+((goal-col)*sp), 1.0); //as suggested below also this doesn't solve the problem
}
```

The only problem I have is that with higher sp values the colors aren't faded completly to the new color. I think the problem is caused by the accuracy which with the shader works.
Doas anyone has an Idea how to increase the accuracy?

**EDIT:**
Could it be that this effect is Driver dependent? I'm using an ATI with the latest drivers maybe someone could try the code on an NVIDIA card?

Comment: Usually, fading the screen is done by rendering a quad on top of everything with blending applied.

Comment: @NicolBolas It looks like it's a post-effect pass anyway.

Comment: @NicolBolas I also tried using an quad on top of everything but also the problem still appears.

Comment: @user2059421: Then you must be doing it wrong. If you use alpha blending with an alpha of 1.0, then you get 100% of the new color.

Comment: @NicolBolas Well yes but I need to fade it slowly so I have no use of alpha 1.0 xD (Should I have suggested this on my main post?)
Sorry for all the trouble is my first time trying to explain my coding problems to someone else ^^

Comment: @Ranking: You need to have an alpha of 1.0. That's the point when the colors have faded *completely*. Until it's 1.0, there will always be some of the other color around.

Answer (score 3):

Let's break it down:

```
float A, B:
float Mix;

float C = A + (B-A) / Mix;
```

Now it's fairly easy to see that Mix has to be infinite to create pure A, so it isn't GLSL fault at all. The normally used equation is as follows

```
float C = A + (B-A) * Mix;
// Let's feed some data:
// Mix = 0 -> C = A;
// Mix = 1 -> C = A + (B - A) = A + B - A = B;
// Mix = 0.5 -> C = A + 0.5*(B - A) = A + 0.5*B - 0.5*A = 0.5*A + 0.5*B
```

Correct, right?

Change your code to:

```
gl_FragColor = vec4(col+((goal-col) * sp), 1.0);
```

And use the range of `<0,1>` in sp instead. Also, shouldn't `sp` be actually float? If all of it's components are equal (IOW `sp.x == sp.y == sp.z`), you can just change it's type and it will work, as [referenced here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14753271/752976).

Comment: The main calculation code I was using was from:[link](http://www.wiki.processing.org/w/Fading_the_screen_to_black/any_color)
They did it using Bit Shifting which equals a division by pow(2, x) right?
I tried your answer BUT the Ghosting (I think the effect was called like that) still appears for values near 0.
And yes sp is used as an vec3 because I want to fade the screen in different speeds for the colors.

Comment: @Ranking, comment on the function you referenced : **// NOTE: This function is currently NOT WORKING**

Comment: It Worked in an earlier version of Processing.
Later I changed it to be able to modify the fade speeds:

`void fadescr(int r, int g, int b, int spr, int spg, int spb) { 
  int red, green, blue;
  loadPixels();
  for (int i = 0; i < pixels.length; i++) {
    red = (pixels[i] >> 16) & 0x000000ff;
    green = (pixels[i] >> 8) & 0x000000ff; 
    blue = pixels[i] & 0x000000ff; 
    pixels[i] = (((red+((r-red)>>spr)) << 16) | ((green+((g-green)>>spg)) << 8) | (blue+((b-blue)>>spb)));
  } 
  updatePixels();
}`

And now I try implement it in glsl. With this function there appeared no Ghosts.

Comment: that's totally different code. If you want to ask about it, make a new question