# What is the difference between vec3(1.,1.,1.) and (1.,1.,1.)

Tags: webgl, glsles

My code compiled without errors, but did not work until I added the vec3 in front of the brackets. The contents were vec3 components, so I would have assumed that GLSL is treating it like a vector or give me an error if it can't but it just accepted it. The error message (*cannot convert from float to highp 3-component vector of float*) only appears if I remove the "-vec3(0.)".

So what is the meaning of just (...) in GLSL and why is it silently accepted when subtracting a vec3?

Examples:

```
//this works:
void mainImage( out vec4 fragColor, in vec2 fragCoord )
{
    vec2 uv = fragCoord.xy/iResolution.xy;
    vec3 col = vec3(uv.x, uv.y, 0.)-vec3(0.);

    fragColor = vec4(vec3(col), 1.);
}
```

.

```
//this doesn't:
void mainImage( out vec4 fragColor, in vec2 fragCoord )
{
    vec2 uv = fragCoord.xy/iResolution.xy;
    vec3 col = (uv.x, uv.y, 0.)-vec3(0.);

    fragColor = vec4(vec3(col), 1.);
}
```

.

```
//this gives the helpful error message
void mainImage( out vec4 fragColor, in vec2 fragCoord )
{
    vec2 uv = fragCoord.xy/iResolution.xy;
    vec3 col = (uv.x, uv.y, 0.);

    fragColor = vec4(vec3(col), 1.);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not exclusive to GLSL but actually a lot of C style languages.

`vec3` is a constructor, an expression like `vec3(1,2,3)` passes the arguments `1` `2` and `3` separated by the comma to the constructor function which will in turn construct a vector with three componenets initialized to the given parameters and return it.

In the case of `(1,2,3)` the comma does not act as a separator but as an operator, making it a list of instructions where the result of the last instruction is propagated to the outside, in this specific case `3`. If you were to write `(1,2,3) + 5` the result would be `8`. You can read more about the comma operator and some common use cases on [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma_operator).

Now comes the GLSL specific part:

`(1.,2.,3.)-vec3(0)` results in `3.-vec3(0)`, as GLSL is all about vector math this is a valid vector-scalar operation, resulting in the scalar operation being applied to the individual components of the vector. in this case this is the same as writing `vec3(3.-0.,3.-0.,3.-0.)`. Another example would be `5.*vec3(2,3,4)` which results in `vec3(2*5,3*5,4*5)` => `vec3(10,15,20)`. This is not a type cast since scalar on vector operations are defined as such, just like transforming a vector by a matrix does not require one to be cast to the other.

Comment: Thanks, could you please elaborate on "List of instructions" - aren't instructions required to be terminated by a semicolon? Are these lists commonly used? And secondly: Isn't 3.-vec3(0) an implicit cast of a float to a vec3 - I thought that GLSLES does not support implicit type conversions.

Comment: Now I get it, so scalar + vector is defined as addition by components in the GLSL specification https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/specs/gl/GLSLangSpec.3.30.pdf on page 56 (related question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14753158/glsl-vector-plus-scalar)